# How to run a python script with selenium using a different proxy each time

Tags: python, selenium

So I basically have a code that opens a website in python using selenium a few times. I am very new to this but I wanted to ask is there a way to run each while loop through a different proxy? Basically I am trying to simulate traffic for a website and I would like to have different ips for each of the times that I run it. If there is a better way to do this than through proxies, I can also do that.

I was also wondering if while doing this there would be a way to see the windows that are open similar to how it is doing it now?

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
x=2
while x>0:
    driver.get("website")
    x-=1
```

Thank you!